# How can we distinguish between audio and video under Android audioflinger

Tags: android, audio, audioflinger

1. we can make distinguish between audio and video if we use android standard api to implement apk to play music/movie. no matter under libaudioflinger or decoder's lib.

> > when decode audio/video in awesomeplayer.cpp,we can judge the source data't type,audio? or video?

2. we can make distinguish the app's type under libaudioflinger

> > use **getCallingPid()**

### Question:

how can we make distinguish 3rd's data source type(Audio?video?)under audioflinger?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"under audioflinger"_? Anyway, the AudioFlinger deals with audio, not with media containers that can contain streams of various types (video, audio, subtitles, ...).

Comment: what's "under audioflinger" means? I mean,in the audiofinger source code. does AF process the PCM data? If APP decode the media content(such as mp3,mp4 .) using android default decoder which define under frameworks/av.we can set some flags from decoder to AF. however,lots of 3rd app has own's decoder,and send the decoded data to  AF directly

Answer (score 0):

yes audioflinger process the pcm data . 
However if you want to set some parameters from Application then you  can use AudioManager's setParametes API and then have a handling for that parameter in AudioFlinger .

AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setParameters("key_value_pair");